# Display variation array in woocommerce cart and checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Am trying add some custom data to my cart. For that I have used

```
   $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($domainProductId, $period, 0, array('Domain Name' => $domain, 'Domain Term' => $period));
```

When I try to display the cart details another function or another page, the entered details is shown in variation array.

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); 
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($items);
```

The items array is

```
       <pre>Array
  (
     [2c098ef710cdd6e95cde45d2c5d6872b] => Array
      (
        [key] => 2c098ef710cdd6e95cde45d2c5d6872b
        [product_id] => 129
        [variation_id] => 0
        [variation] => Array
            (
                [Domain Name] => domainnn
                [Domain Term] => 1
            )

        [quantity] => 1
        [data_hash] => b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0
        [line_tax_data] => Array
            (
                [subtotal] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [total] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [line_subtotal] => 95
        [line_subtotal_tax] => 0
        [line_total] => 95
        [line_tax] => 0
        [data] => WC_Product_Simple Object
            (
                [object_type:protected] => product
                [post_type:protected] => product
                [cache_group:protected] => products
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => net
                        [slug] => net
```

How can i display the variation array in my cart and checkout page.?